# SFTP upload script, there is no key

Tags: ssh, scripts, cron, sftp

I need to upload a file to a server.

The server uploads using SFTP. After authentication, any command execution is forbidden, so I cannot SSH directly in, I need to get directly into the SFTP subsystem.

For instance.

`ssh -N user@example.com` works fine, except I can't SFTP anything.

However, I can do `sftp user@example.com` just fine.

**Problem:** I need to automate this, the authentication is keyboard-interactive, not key-based. I don't own the server I'm connecting to, they simply said *"Here's the password, upload the files every week."* And nobody over there knows anything about keys or stuff like that.

`sftp -b` Batch scripts won't allow keyboard interactive auth.

I'm sick of manually uploading the file. They sent the 8-charecter password over unencrypted email and it contains 3 of the same numbers at the end and one dictionary word (ie "Words777") -- lets pretend security really isn't an issue here.

Can I make the SSH key from just the password? Remember, I don't have access to the other server. Can I script this some way? I've attempted using different packages, and even `rsync` to do the upload, but they all want to access SSH directly instead of directly getting into the SFTP subsystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) that lets you script for situations like this.

`sudo apt-get install expect`

Set up a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=""
USER=""
PASS=""

# Sorry for the offensive "assword", it's to cope with "Password" and "password".

VAR=$(expect -c "
  spawn sftp $USER@$HOST

  expect \"assword:\"
  send \"$PASS\r\"

  expect \"\\\\$\"
  send \"ls\r\"

  expect -re \"$USER.*\"
  send \"exit\"
")

echo "==============="
echo "$VAR"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you create a ssh key *without* protecting it with a "passphrase", you can skip the keyboard interactive part and thus easily create the upload script you need. [See for example here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/linux-unix-bsd/create-rsa-dsa-keys-ssh/) :

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "Your Name" -f your_key`

This will create the necessary files, you then just have to copy the public one (*.pub) on the remote server.

Comment: I don't have access to the other server.

Comment: You only need the password to copy the public key on the server. It remain to check if the server is configured to support key authentication.

Comment: Where on the server? I only have access to a small sub directory.

Comment: @user11239: You only need access to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` under your remote home directory. Here a guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: Not everyone has access to ~/.ssh/, so this is not always an option - unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).

Example:

```
(sleep 2; echo password) | socat - EXEC: "sftp -o batchmode=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -b batchfile user@host",pty,setsid,ctty
```